# WPF popup gets disappear magically

Tags: c#, wpf, button, popup

WPF popup is not working as expected for me. So the behavior is show popup when mouse enters on "Test: button and after that Clicking on "Close" button which is on popup will hide the popup. Everything works fine until I left click on "Test" button. After that the Mouse event event gets fired on "Test" button but the popup does not show up.

It would be great if someone will be able to help me out here.

Thanks,
Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Button x:Name="btnTest"  Width="100" Height="25" 
                MouseEnter="btnTest_MouseEnter">Test Button</Button>
        <Popup Name="MyPopup"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnTest}"
               Placement="Mouse"
               StaysOpen="False">
            <StackPanel Background="PaleGreen">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">I am a popup</Label>
                <Button Click="Hide_Click" Content="Close"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    private void Hide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
    private void btnTest_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: your test button doesn't have a on click event...or did I miss something?

Comment: @steve although it does not have click callback you should be able to see the explained behavior.

Comment: you said every thing works fine until you click on the button. But the button click is not firing an event to open the popup and StaysOpen="False". So what exactly are you expecting..

Comment: @Steve so when the mouse enters on "Test" button the popup should open up. This does not happen once you click on "Test" button. 1. take mouse pointer on "Test" button and you will see popup. 2. click on "Test" button. 3. Take mouse pointer again on "Test" button and popup will not show up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code, and I do not understand why it worked.
However, I tried to implement your desired functionality with triggers, etc. 
I've tested it and it seems to work:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Button x:Name="btnTest"  Width="100" Height="25" Content="Test Button">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames 

            Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
            Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Popup Name="MyPopup"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnTest}"
           Placement="Mouse"
           StaysOpen="False">
            <StackPanel Background="PaleGreen">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">I am a popup</Label>
                <Button  Content="Close">
                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames                 
            Storyboard.TargetName="MyPopup" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
            Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm not sure if there is a shorter way; probably there is.

Comment: thanks. it works fine. By the way things like this should work out of the box. Sorry that not having enough reputation does not letting me to give you credit for this.